# Stata longwise average

Tags: date, stata

I'm using Stata and trying to compute conditional means based on time/date. For each store I want to calculate mean (inventory) per year. If there are missing year gaps, then I want to take the mean from the closest two dates' inventory values.

I've used (below) to get overall means per store, but I need more granularity.

```
egen mean_inv = mean(inventory), by (store)
```

I've also tried this loop with similar results:

```
by id, sort: gen v1'=_n'
forvalues x = 1/'=n'{
by store: sum inventory if v1==`x'
replace mean_inv= r(mean) if v1==`x'
}
```

Visually, I want mean inventory per store: (store id is not sequential)

```
5/1/2003 2/3/2006 8/9/2006  3/5/2007   6/9/2007   2/1/2008
   13        18        12       15       24          11
     [mean1]    [mean2]   [mean3]   [mean4]   [mean5]


store   date    inventory
 1  16750   17
 1  18234   16
 1  15844   13
 1  17111   14
 1  17870   13
 1  16929   13.5
 1  17503   13
 4  15987   18
 4  15896   16
 4  18211   16
 4  17154   18
 4  17931   24
 4  16776   23
12  16426   26
12  17681   17
12  16386   17
12  16603   18
12  17034   16
12  17205   16
42  15798   18
42  16022   18
42  17496   16
42  17870   18
42  16204   18
42  16778   14
33  18053   23
33  16086   13
33  16450   21
33  17374   19
33  16814   19
33  15834   16
33  16167   16
56  17686   16
56  17623   18
56  17231   20
56  15978   16
56  16811   15
56  17861   20
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to relate your code to the word description of your problem.

Your `egen` call calculates means by `store`, not year.

Your longer fragment does not make complete sense given lack of definitions and at least one typo.

Note that your variable `v1` contains identifiers that run 1 up within groups of `store`, and does not distinguish different values of `store`, as you (seem to) imply. It strains credibility that it produces results anywhere near those by the `egen` call.

`n` is not defined and the code evaluating it is presumably intended to be

```
`=n'
```

If you calculate

```
 by store: sum inventory if v1 == `x'
```

several means will be calculated in turn but *only* the last to be calculated will be accessible as `r(mean)`.

The sample data are unrelated to the problem. There is no `year` variable and even if the `date`s are Stata daily dates, they are all dates within 1960.

Setting all that aside, suppose you have variables `store`, `inventory` and `year`.  You can try

```
 collapse inventory, by(store year) 
 fillin store year 
 ipolate inventory year, gen(inventory2) by(store)
```

The `collapse` produces a reduced dataset of means. The `ipolate` interpolates across gaps, as you ask. `fillin` may not be adequate to give all the `store` and `year` combinations you want and you may need to add further years manually before the interpolation. If you want to put these results back with the original data, that's a `merge`.

In total, this is a pretty messy question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick. While I am calculating means by store, I need the mean per store per year. I was trying to do that through my egen statement.
The year information is not uniform, but I will try your collapse and fillin options.

Comment: Your edits to the code fix some errors, but introduce others. This won't help anyone, unfortunately. For example, the first two lines in your block of five are both illegal, but for different reasons.